# SpringBoot Mvc tomcat

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

Why is it highlighted with red colour [image]

Why does the groupId highlighted red

Answer (score 0):

You have unloaded dependencies. Each IDE has the ability to force a download.

Answer (score 0):

Try run `mvn install` in terminal or if you use IDEA Maven->Lifecycle->install

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Try nuking your .m2 folder, and then pull dependencies again. I usually do it like this: delete everything from .m/repo, I go to intellij and add space in pom.xml and delete it so it offers me to pull changes that were made in pom.xml ( this is mostly enabled by default to follow changes in your pom.xml )

If that does not help, you can always run from your terminal in application root

mvn clean - clear dependencies so you get something like a clean slate

mvn install - initiates the pulling of dependencies again